# What is Open-source diffusion model in prestashop?

Tags: model, prestashop, software-design

I am new to prestashop and by seeing prestashop about us page there they mentioned prestasop is based upon a open-source diffusion model. what it means?

> *PrestaShop Software PrestaShop SA editor of the e-commerce software PrestaShop offers to merchants, through its solution, a complete
>   platform with the best tools to manage their e-commerce on a daily
>   basis. PrestaShop is a complete, progressive and easily adaptable
>   solution for online sale. PrestaShop is based upon an **Open-source
>   diffusion model** to enable each one of you to modify the software to
>   your convenience .The PrestaShop solution often enriches with new
>   features and partner services. The PrestaShop solution, satisfies more
>   than 50,000 merchants around the world, is free to download on the
>   website PrestaShop.com, property of PrestaShop SA.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is very general but this should answer it: http://www.prestashop.com/en/osl-license